# Function does not give desired result

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to define a function for Fibonacci series but the code is not working. I can't resolve the issues and need help to fix the problem. Whenever I am trying to call this function, last value of the series comes always greater than n, which I don't want

```
 def fib(n):
        Series = [0,1]
        if n>1:
            while Series[-1]<=n:
                c=Series[-2]+Series[-1]
                Series.append(c)
                if Series[-1]>n:
                break
            return Series
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a reserved keyword as a variable name (`Series`). Use something like `fibs` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is really good, just the indentation of the `return` is wrong. Just align it properly.

```
def fib(n):
    Series = [0,1]
    if n>1:
        while Series[-1]<=n:
            c=Series[-2]+Series[-1]
            Series.append(c)
    return Series
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But still there is some problem in code. I f I want to get the series upto n then it returns a series with last number more than n. Could you tell, why it is coming like that?

Comment: It is because `while` is already appending the list before returning the value. the Fibonacci Sequence sums the last 2 values and as `while` loop checks for the condition, it is already appended. one hack you can use is `return Series[:-1]`. Also you don't require the `if` loop in the code. And as @ukemi mentioned, avoid reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this:

```
def fibo(n):
    l = [0,1]
    for i in range(2,n+1): 
        l += [l[i-1] + l[i-2]]
    return l
```

Comment: No, I am trying to make a series where a given value is sum of last two value. Your code also stops after first iteration like me and did not give desired result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Fibonacci sequence up to n:

```
def fib(n):
    series = [0,1]
    if n > 1:
        c = 1
        while c <= n:
            series.append(c)
            c = series[-2] + series[-1]
    return series
```